# how to resolved django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL: database "graphite.db" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, graphite

I am trying to install graphite in ubuntu box, I am running on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-43-generic x86_64)
These are the setting in my local_settings.py file for the database

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'NAME': 'graphite.db',
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'USER': 'graphite',
'PASSWORD': '\*\*\*\*\*',
'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
'PORT': '5432'
}
}
```

Getting the following error while executing sudo graphite-manage migrate auth

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
return func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
return func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
connection = Database.connect(\*\*conn_params)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
conn = \_connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, \*\*kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "graphite.db" does not exist
```

I assure that the graphite user has been created and enough permissions has been given.
tried with different engine like django.db.backends.postgresql, but still facing the same issue

Comment: As the error reports, it is the database, not the user, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`graphite.db` does not exist because it hasn't been created, you might have to create the database manually and set priviledges before running `sudo graphite-manage migrate auth`